# VSCode extension: treat function parameter names as imports in JS

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to create a VSCode extension that would allow me to work with non-typical AngularJS files on ServiceNow platform.

Angular Services are saved as single .js files which contain a single function with a name that's the same as the service. Arguments of this function are always dependencies.

```js
function exampleService(anotherService, $timeout, $q) {
  // service code here
}
```

When another service name is included in the arguments of a function then VSCode should:

- find service code by service name (using function name)
- assume that `serviceName = new serviceName()` inside a service function

It's very important that other services are correctly recognised. When playing around with autocomplete functionality I was able to make `serviceName = serviceName` but I had issues with making VSCode assume that it's `serviceName = new serviceName`.

For common AngularJS dependencies like `$q` or `$timeout` I can simply create `.d.ts` files as they are static.

I don't want to write a complete logic of finding the necessary file, interpreting it etc. as I think I should be able to leverage the VSCode's functionality as it already supports giving autocomplete suggestions for includes/imports. I'd like to intercept that and treat function arguments as imports.

Comment: those `autocomplete suggestions for includes/imports` are created by the language server of the used language, create a `CompletionItemProvider` and suggest completions based on what is typed where

Comment: @rioV8 I'm not sure if `CompletionItemProvider` is the correct approach in this case as I'm not only trying to tackle the issue of displaying hints for methods/variables but I would also like the entire variable to be treated as another class. Basically I would like user to be able to hover over the variable and get the definition, the autocomplete with methods is also required so that is why I think I might try to approach the issue from the other side around